# How to Get List of MySQL Databases even if the Size of Database is 0.000MB?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the list of Databases along with the size of each! I tried many queries and the following one works but it will only show me Databases having At least one record, or, in other words, It will only list databases having Size More than 0.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT table_schema 'database', sum( data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 'size' FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

It's Obvious that I won't get the list of the Database having 0 tables using this query because it looks for Tables and it's size in `information_schema` table.

How can I modify this query to make it show me databases having no Tables too? I've tried each query given on the StackOverflow Questions related to MySQL Database size.

**Update:** I am working in PHP and If the Full query is not Available, Show me a way to get the list of databases with size even if It's possible with PHP in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of schemata from the `SCHEMATA` table, even for schemata that have no tables.

```
SELECT s.schema_name AS 'database', 
  SUM( t.data_length + t.index_length) / 1024 / 1024 AS 'size' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON s.schema_name=t.table_schema 
GROUP BY s.schema_name;
```

Comment: I am not so expert at SQL, Here is the error i got after running this query. Correct me `#1054 - Unknown column 's.schema.name' in 'on clause'` ...

Comment: My apologies, I had a typo in the join condition. I've fixed it above. You might want to learn SQL if you need to use it.